# Should I use configure await in all methods or only in the first method?

Tags: c#, async-await, configureawait

I have a library with async methods and I have read that for libraries, it is recommended to use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

For example, if I have something like:

```
public async Task myMethod01()
{
    await myMethod02();
}

private async Task myMethod02()
{
    await myMethod03();
}

private async Task myMethod03()
{
    await anotherMetodAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

The library user can only use `method01`, the other 2 methods are private because they are auxliar methods for the main method `method01()`.

But I don't know if it is needed to use `ConfigureAwait` only in the first method of the chain call or I should to use in all of them.

Comment: You should use it all the way down in library code. [I have an example](https://contrivedexample.com/2017/12/04/configureawait-sometimes-saves-the-day-everytime/) of exactly how not doing that can bite the consumer of your library.

Comment: Every time you **don't** use `ConfigureAwait` you are capturing the context. And you don't want to capture the context in libraries. So use `ConfigureAwait` everywhere.

Comment: The decision of whether or not to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` should be made on a method-by-method basis. For each method, if it doesn't need the context, it should use `ConfigureAwait(false)` for every `await` in that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### tl;dr

**Yes**, it is needed in order to ensure that all of your asynchronous continuations within your library code are executed on a thread pool thread (depending on the [SynchronizationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext)/[TaskScheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler) in use).

#### Would you like to know more?

[Task.ConfigureAwait(Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait)

- `true` attempts to marshal *the remainder of the async method* back to the original context captured
- `false` schedules *the remainder of the async method* on a thread pool thread

Consider the following WPF example:
WPF uses the [DispatcherSynchronizationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchersynchronizationcontext) to resume asynchronous continuations on the UI context, because a background thread cannot update the contents of Controls.

```cs
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    logger.LogInformation(Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread); //false -> GUI context

    await CompleteAsynchronously();

    logger.LogInformation(Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread); //false -> GUI context

    await CompleteAsynchronously().ConfigureAwait(false);

    logger.LogInformation(Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread); //true
}

private async Task CompleteAsynchronously()
{
    logger.LogInformation(Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread); //false -> GUI context

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)).ConfigureAwait(false);

    logger.LogInformation(Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread); //true
}
```

Here, you see that the `continueOnCapturedContext` flag of the called method has no effect on the caller. Yet, the called method runs (or at least starts to run) on the thread that the caller was running on, of course.

However, the capturing of the current context (either the current `SynchronizationContext`; if null then the current `TaskScheduler`) only occurs when an incomplete Task is awaited. If the Task completes synchronously, `continueOnCapturedContext` has no effect and the remainder of the method continues to run synchronously on the current thread.

```cs
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    logger.LogInformation(Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread); //false -> GUI context

    await CompleteSynchronously().ConfigureAwait(false);

    logger.LogInformation(Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread); //false -> GUI context
}

private async Task CompleteSynchronously()
{
    await Task.Delay(0);
}
```

So, in your library code (assuming you never require con­text), you should always use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in order to ensure that no context is captured for asynchronous continuations, regardless of the framework calling into your assemblies (e.g. WPF, ASP.NET Core, Console, ...).

For more details, have a look at *Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming* (i.a. `ConfigureAwait`) in this [MSDN Magazine Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) by [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/).

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `ConfigureAwait(false)` on all the async calls. When this is not done, the first async call (without the `ConfigureAwait(false)`) will take the SynchronizationContext and this could cause a deadlock in certain conditions (like on ASP.NET) when you wait synchronously on that call.

My advice is to read [this article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) written by Stephen Cleary. The part you are interested in is:

> Using `ConfigureAwait(false)` to avoid deadlocks is a dangerous
>   practice. You would have to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` for every await
>   in the transitive closure of all methods called by the blocking code,
>   including all third- and second-party code. Using
>   `ConfigureAwait(false)` to avoid deadlock is at best just a hack).